# As imagens publicadas em minha página não aparecem

Tags: php, css

Eu criei três páginas no meu site com o elementor, porém as imagens utilizadas não aparecem em nenhuma delas após a publicação. Solicitei o suporte do meu provedor de hospedagem, que identificou como um erro no código do site e que, por ser problema com o desenvolvimento, não poderiam resolver. A atendente me indicou vocês e, inclusive, me enviou um print do problema que está ocorrendo. Procurei nas perguntas daqui, mas vou ser franco, eu não entendo nada de programação, sei muito pouco - ou melhor - quase nada sobre códigos, principalmente no wordpress.

Assim, estou enviando este questionamento com a imagem do problema solicitando que alguém possa me ajudar.

Agradeço desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Al Santana! Me parece que existe um problema com as rotas em seu código. Seria bom poder ver o seu código para te ajudar.

Comment: Ok. Como eu posso te mandar o código?

Comment: poste o seu codigo html aqui mesmo no stackoverflow